# Grouping api results by title

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Here is my api call:

```
beforeMount(){
  this.get(`...`).then(data => {this.results = data.results;});
}
```

Here is my returned data structure.

```
Store - object
    name
    id
    products: [Array of objects]
        0: Object
            id: 1
            type: Object
                id: 543
                title: string
                ediable: object
                    categoryName: string
                    categoryId: number
        1: Object
            id: 2
            type: Object
                id: 544
                title: string
                ediable: object
                    categoryName: string
                    categoryId: number
        2: Object
            id: 3
            type: Object
                id: 545
                title: string
                ediable: object
                    categoryName: string
                    categoryId: number
```

So fo example lets say i have

```
ediable.categoryName = fruit
type.title = apple
ediable.categoryName = dairy
type.title = yogurt
ediable.categoryName = fruit
type.title = banana
ediable.categoryName = grains
type.title = bagels
ediable.categoryName = grains
type.title = bread
ediable.categoryName = fruit
type.title = strawberry
ediable.categoryName = dairy
type.title = milk
ediable.categoryName = grains
type.title = muffins
ediable.categoryName = dairy
type.title = cheese
```

in my view page i have:

fruit - apple
dairy - yogurt
fruit - banana
grains - bagels
grains - bread
fruit - strawberry
dairy - milk
grains - muffins
dairy - cheese

I would like for my view to be:
fruit - apple, banana, strawberry
grains - bagels, bread, muffins
dairy - yogurt, milk, cheese

I read about using reduce or groupBy but i don't seem to get them to work. and i wonder what possible solutions for this issue. It seems like a very straight forward propblem but somehow i am having trouble wrapping my head around this.

UPDATES:

So this is how far i got:

```
productCategories: Model[] = [];

Array(data).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let key;
  for(let x = 0; x<curr.products.length; x++){
    key = curr.products[x].type.ediable.categoryName;
    this.productCategories.push(
      ...acc,
      [key]:[...(acc[key] || []), curr.products[x].type.title])
  }
}, {});
```

But i am showing an error for `[key]:` that states:

```
let key: any
Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Model'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'any[]'
```

STORE OBJECT:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "store": "Sample Store"
    "products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "type": {
            "id":1,
            "parentId": 100,
            "term": "Banana",
            "ediable": {
                "id": 100,
                "term": "Fruits"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "type": {
            "id":3,
            "parentId": 101,
            "term": "Apple",
            "ediable": {
                "id": 101,
                "term": "Fruits"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "type": {
            "id":3,
            "parentId": 102,
            "term": "Muffins",
            "ediable": {
                "id": 102,
                "term": "Grains"
            }
        }
    }, {"id": 4,
        "type": {
            "id":4,
            "parentId": 103,
            "term": "Cheese",
            "ediable": {
                "id": 103,
                "term": "Dairy"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "type": {
            "id":5,
            "parentId": 104,
            "term": "Bread",
            "ediable": {
                "id": 104,
                "term": "Grains"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "type": {
            "id":6,
            "parentId": 105,
            "term": "Yogurt",
            "ediable": {
                "id": 105,
                "term": "Dairy"
            }
        }
    }],
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `reduce` docs that I have linked below and also the answer I have provided. In my example `acc` is the accumulated value and `curr` is the current value. That function being passed to `reduce` is called for every value in the array so there is no need to do a `for` loop within this function.

Comment: Can you give me an example `Store` object in JavaScript object form?

Comment: @BradyHanna i have updated post with object example

Comment: I have uploaded an updated answer that uses your new `Store` model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) will do the trick. We want to collect the similar categories into the same array. At each step we either append to an existing `categoryName` or add a new key which is what `[key]: [...(acc[key] || []), curr.title]` does.

```js
const data = {
    id: 1,
    store: 'Sample Store',
    products: [
        {
            id: 1,
            type: {
                id: 1,
                parentId: 100,
                term: 'Banana',
                ediable: {
                    id: 100,
                    term: 'Fruits'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            type: {
                id: 3,
                parentId: 101,
                term: 'Apple',
                ediable: {
                    id: 101,
                    term: 'Fruits'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            type: {
                id: 3,
                parentId: 102,
                term: 'Muffins',
                ediable: {
                    id: 102,
                    term: 'Grains'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            type: {
                id: 4,
                parentId: 103,
                term: 'Cheese',
                ediable: {
                    id: 103,
                    term: 'Dairy'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            type: {
                id: 5,
                parentId: 104,
                term: 'Bread',
                ediable: {
                    id: 104,
                    term: 'Grains'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            type: {
                id: 6,
                parentId: 105,
                term: 'Yogurt',
                ediable: {
                    id: 105,
                    term: 'Dairy'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};

const products = data.products.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const key = curr.type.ediable.term;
    return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: [...(acc[key] || []), curr.type.term]
    };
}, {});

const mappedData = {
    ...data,
    products
};

console.log(mappedData);
// output of results
// { id: 1,
//  store: 'Sample Store',
//  products:
//   { Fruits: [ 'Banana', 'Apple' ],
//     Grains: [ 'Muffins', 'Bread' ],
//     Dairy: [ 'Cheese', 'Yogurt' ] } }
```

Comment: I just tried implementing this but i am running into an error on build: ` Property 'reduce' does not exist on type  [name of my model]`

Comment: try performing it on `Store.products` or whatever property is the products array. For example do `Store.products.reduce ...`

Comment: I updated my post with your suggested answer.. i had to make couple adjustments and i am getting an error - if you can take a look and maybe have an idea of why i am getting the error

Comment: where you able to get that console log to show the data? For me, i am getting a console log that it can't find ediable of undefined.

Comment: Yep that's the `console.log` of that exact code running. Try copy and paste my exact example and see if that works for you. [codepen](https://codepen.io/bradyhanna/pen/rRQZYG?editors=0011)

Comment: Thank you so much for sticking around to help me resolve this. I works now!