# Using .reduce() to group data results

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

This question is a follow up from this post: [Grouping api results by title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230802/grouping-api-results-by-title)

I have implemented the reduce but i am getting a build error.

Here is my code:

```
  productCategories: Model[] = [];
  beforeMount(){
    this.get(`...`).then(data => {
        Array(data).reduce((acc, curr) => {
          let key;
          for(let x = 0; x<curr.products.length; x++){
            key = curr.products[x].type.ediable.categoryName;
            this.productCategories.push(
              ...acc,
              [key]:[...(acc[key] || []), curr.products[x].type.title])
          }
        }, {});
    });
}
```

And this is the build error that i am getting for `[key]:`

```
let key: any
Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Model'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'any[]'
```

I am not sure what this error means to go about resolving it.

Here is the information for my results:

Getting data:

```
beforeMount(){
  this.get(`...`).then(data => {this.results = data.results;});
}
```

data structure:

```
Store - object
    name
    id
    products: [Array of objects]
        0: Object
            id: 1
            type: Object
                id: 543
                title: string
                ediable: object
                    categoryName: string
                    categoryId: number
        1: Object
            id: 2
            type: Object
                id: 544
                title: string
                ediable: object
                    categoryName: string
                    categoryId: number
        2: Object
            id: 3
            type: Object
                id: 545
                title: string
                ediable: object
                    categoryName: string
                    categoryId: number
```

Example of data:

```
ediable.categoryName = fruit
type.title = apple
ediable.categoryName = dairy
type.title = yogurt
ediable.categoryName = fruit
type.title = banana
ediable.categoryName = grains
type.title = bagels
ediable.categoryName = grains
type.title = bread
ediable.categoryName = fruit
type.title = strawberry
ediable.categoryName = dairy
type.title = milk
ediable.categoryName = grains
type.title = muffins
ediable.categoryName = dairy
type.title = cheese
```

in my view page i have:

fruit - apple
dairy - yogurt
fruit - banana
grains - bagels
grains - bread
fruit - strawberry
dairy - milk
grains - muffins
dairy - cheese

I would like for my view to be:

fruit - apple, banana, strawberry
grains - bagels, bread, muffins
dairy - yogurt, milk, cheese

Comment: You do `push(...acc,` but `acc` is an object, not an array

Comment: Then you don't return anything, so on the second iteration `acc` is undefined

Comment: @CristianTraìna i could add the return in my for loop but then i only get one category returned when i am expecting 4.

Comment: Please post the input and expected output. `.push(
      ...acc,
      [key]:[...(acc[key] || []), curr.products[x].type.title])` is not a valid syntax

Comment: @bluePearl no, returning out of the for loop doesn't break iterations. Are you sure to know how `reduce` works? And are you sure to know how functional programming works?

Comment: @adiga what i am trying to do is push the categories so i can iterate over them to display on the view.

Comment: @adiga updated post with more info

Comment: @CristianTraìna yes the returns causes my code to exit the beforeMount() once hit and doesn't hit the for loop again (tested while debugging)

Comment: Resolved through this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230802/grouping-api-results-by-title/55232325?noredirect=1#comment97309250_55232325